# Oracle timestamp: change time value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a timestamp field in Oracle db with some date and time. I need to set time to be 00:00. Like '2011-09-01 17:55:00' -> '2011-09-01 00:00:00' Can you please advise optimal ways to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `TRUNC()` function, as in:

```
UPDATE table
SET timestamp_column = TRUNC(timestamp_column)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Note that the OP specified timestamp, not date, but the answer still works.